# Using IO::Event to detect new files in a directory

Tags: perl

I am trying to use [IO::Event](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aEvent) to detect when a new file is added to a directory. I am new to the IO::Event library, and would like to know if it can be easily implemented.

I tried the code below to see if I can get it to do something with no luck. It crashed when I tried to use `opendir` instead of `open`.

I am just looking to see if this library can provide me with what I am looking for. I don't need a solution in plain Perl as I can code it myself. the only reason I am looking at this is because I want to use [Proc::JobQueue::EventQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc%3a%3aJobQueue%3a%3aEventQueue). I can code the solution just using [Proc::JobQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc%3a%3aJobQueue), but thought that this might be cleaner.

```
#!perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Event;

open my $dirhandle,'/some/path/here/';

my $event = IO::Event->new($dirhandle);

Event::loop();

close $dirhandle;

sub ie_input{
    print "ie_input called\n";
}

sub ie_read_ready{
    print "ie_read_ready called\n";
}

sub ie_werror{
    print "ie_werrory called\n";
}

sub ie_output{
    print "ie_output called\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use [File::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aChangeNotify) and [File::ChangeNotify::Watcher](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aChangeNotify%3a%3aWatcher) for that.

```
use File::ChangeNotify;

my $watcher =
    File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher
        ( directories => [ '/my/path', '/my/other' ],
          regex       => qr/\.(?:pm|conf|yml)$/,
        );

if ( my @events = $watcher->new_events() ) { ... }

$watcher->watch($handler);
```